# awk to print a pattern

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a huge text file where I want to print the column contains the word ````

```
LastRechargeDate= xxxx
```

where:

`xxxx is deferent dates`

this word/pattern is mostly can be found in column 13. so, I used the following awk command

`nawk -F "," | print '{print $1, $13}'`

my issue here is that, the word i want to print in some lines is located in column 23, some lines in column 19

Comment: How is supposed the program to understand which column is the correct to print, especially if there are more date columns? Is there a kind of header or the date column is a unique date column?

Comment: I am thinking of loop. inside the  loop, I search on the expected column and if my word is found, print it along with proceeding 6 chars. but don't know the synatx

Comment: Is it a fixed word to be searched? Is it a pattern?

Comment: You can loop over all fields like `awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="word") {print $1,$i;break}}' file`. If it is a pattern , then the if section must be `if ($i ~ /pattern/)`. In for i skip field1 , since i suppose you want to exlude this field. You can start your for by number 12 if you know that your word will be in a field >12. Break is not necessary, but speeds things up (if you find it, then break the for - no more fields processing).

Comment: the word is fix but followed by data which is not fixed. i want to print the word along with date

Comment: Is above for usage helpfull?

Comment: Are you relying on the space char as the field Sep, and do some of the "wrong" data have extra spaces in the column data? Does the file already have either <tab> or `|` chars defining the columns, if so the switch to `awk -F\| '{...}'` . Else consider that we need sample data to help with the problem AND that we only need 3-4 columns of data (with 5-6 columns in the bad data) to help you solve your problem. Please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your Q. Good luck.

Comment: @George Vasiliou, yes it is helpful, I need more elaboration. i.e. search for my pattern in columns 13, 18, 23, etc and print it wherever is found along with column 2. can u plz write a sample code?

Comment: I gave you a draft code above...  above code loops in all the fields and if finds your "word" prints $1 and the field that has your word ($i). Maybe is better to give some realisitc data of your file to be more clear what you have as input and you need as output.

Answer (score 0):

assuming date is not a regex complication ...

```
awk -F ',' -v Pat="LastRechargeDate= xxxx" ' '$0 ~ Pat { for (i=2;i<NF;i++) if ( $i ~ Pat ) print $1 "," $i }' YourFile
```

print line and field that CONTAIN your pattern (no only equal)